# How to Show Multiple Map Annotations in iOS using webservice?

Tags: ios, iphone, cllocationmanager, mkannotation

I am using webservice. I am recieving XML response.

I read my data perfectly.I want to show that data on map view but I am not able to show. viewForAnnotation call only once but It has to call 11 times. I do not know why it is happenning.

Please check my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 65, 320, 508)];
    mapView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.mapView setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [self sendRequestToServer];
}


- (void) startXmlParsing
{

    ///////////////// Start XML PArsing From Here  ////////
    NSXMLDocument* xmlDoc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:_serverData options:0 error:nil]; 
    NSXMLElement* rootElement = [xmlDoc rootElement];   

    NSArray* spotList = [rootElement elementsForName:@"spot"];
    NSLog(@"driversList %lu ", (unsigned long)[spotList count]);   

    int k = [spotList count];
    NSLog(@"k is %d ", k);    // K is 11

    int i = 0;


    // NSXMLElement* firstElement;              
    for (firstElement in spotList) {      objectAtIndex

        i++;

        NSLog(@"i is: %d",i);  // For Checking once again is it call 11 time or not

        str_id            = [firstElement stringValueForNode:@"ID"];
        str_username      = [firstElement stringValueForNode:@"username"];
        str_streetnumber  = [firstElement stringValueForNode:@"streetnumber"];
        str_streetname    = [firstElement stringValueForNode:@"streetname"];
        str_suburb        = [firstElement stringValueForNode:@"suburb"];
        str_postalcode    = [firstElement stringValueForNode:@"postalcode"];
        str_state         = [firstElement stringValueForNode:@"state"];
        str_country       = [firstElement stringValueForNode:@"country"];
        str_lat           = [firstElement stringValueForNode:@"lat"];
        str_lng           = [firstElement stringValueForNode:@"lng"];

        [self click_method];  // This method is calling only once "viewForAnnotation" This  is the problem and I am not able to show my annotations on map View only one annotation is calling on map view. I am calling this methed here for the purpose of showing all the data I collected from webservice to show on the map all at once & together.

    }
```

}

```
-(void)click_method{

      // [mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];

      locationManager.delegate = self;
      locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
      [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
  }


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation   *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation

{


     // In This I dont want geo coding I want to give direct lattitute and longitude with  title as I am getting lattitude and longitude from web service now, how to give lat & long directly on Mkmapannotation?


    NSString *str_Address2 = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@",str_streetnumber,str_streetname,str_state,str_country, str_suburb,str_postalcode];
    NSLog(@"Address is: %@",str_Address2);

    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:str_Address2 completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Fehlar %@", error.localizedDescription);
        return ;
    }

    for (id object in placemarks) {


        CLPlacemark *placemark = object;

        ////////////////////// Title ///////////////////////

        MapAnnotation *mapannotaion = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@",str_streetnumber,str_streetname,str_state,str_country, str_suburb,str_postalcode] subtitle:placemark.subLocality  coordinate:placemark.location.coordinate];

        NSLog(@"Postal Code is: %@",placemark.postalCode);
        NSLog(@"Locality is: %@",placemark.locality);
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:mapannotaion];

        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        region.center = mapannotaion.coordinate;

        MKCoordinateSpan span;
        span.latitudeDelta  = 0.01;
        span.longitudeDelta = 0.01;
        region.span = span;

        [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

    }

}];

// Stop Location Manager
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView2 viewForAnnotation:(id  <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{


MKAnnotationView *a = [ [ MKAnnotationView alloc ] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];

if ( a == nil )
    a = [ [ MKAnnotationView alloc ] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier: @"currentloc" ];


NSLog(@"%f",a.annotation.coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"%f",a.annotation.coordinate.longitude);

 CLLocation* currentLocationMap = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:a.annotation.coordinate.latitude longitude:a.annotation.coordinate.longitude];
// [self coordinatesToDMS:currentLocationMap];


MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:a reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
if(a.annotation.coordinate.longitude == mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude ||  a.annotation.coordinate.latitude == mapView2.userLocation.coordinate.latitude  )
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:MKUserLocation.class])
    {

        return nil;
    }
        }
else
{

}

annView.animatesDrop = YES;
annView.draggable = YES;

annView.canShowCallout = YES;

return annView;

}
```

Comment: Why are you calling geocodeAddressString if spotList already contains lat and lng?  Why are you calling addAnnotation in didUpdateToLocation?  What does getting the user location have to do with adding the annotations in spotList?

Comment: Yes eaxctly I want to remove extra code but I dont know waht part should I remove. I am new and I change something it gets crash so I am not able to figure out the things. Only You catch all the things  what I want to implement.

Comment: This is for Mac, right?  It must be for Mac (not iOS) since the code is using NSXMLDocument (which doesn't exist in iOS).  If you're planning to do this in iOS, you'll need to use NSXMLParser instead.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple Docs: `viewForAnnotation` is the delegate method, that gets called for every annotation object.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation

    Returns the view associated with the specified annotation object.
```

From your code, it seems you are making just one annotation object in `didUpdateToLocation` method: `[self.mapView addAnnotation:mapannotaion];`

Hence iOS system, is presenting only one view for annotation.

Comment: Thanks Sir for your reply, how I add all annotation on map view? I want to show all lattitude and longitude on map view with annotation which I get from webservice.

Comment: I guess you have an array of latitude and longitudes. You can create 11 instances of MapAnnotation Object, using the latitude and longitude and add these objects as subview to map view.

Comment: Not understand Sir, I am new please give some more explanation.

Comment: In the for loop of your startXMLParsing methods, create objects of MapAnnotation class like this MapAnnotation *mapannotaion = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@",str_streetnumber,str_streetname,str_state,str_country, str_suburb,str_postalcode] subtitle:placemark.subLocality  coordinate:placemark.location.coordinate]; where coordinate is CLLocationCoordinate2D object. Learn more by reading Apple Docs.

Answer (score 0):

-(void) centerMap
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;

```
CLLocationDegrees maxLat = -90;

CLLocationDegrees maxLon = -180;

CLLocationDegrees minLat = 120;

CLLocationDegrees minLon = 150;

NSMutableArray *temp=[NSArray arrayWithArray:reports];

for (int i=0; i<[temp count];i++) {
    BasicMapAnnotation*customAnnotation=[[BasicMapAnnotation alloc]init];
    customAnnotation.latitude = [[[temp objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"PostLattitude"]floatValue];
    customAnnotation.longitude =[[[temp objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"PostLongitude"]floatValue];


    UIImage*pinImage=[[UIImage alloc]init];
    NSString *imageUrl=[[temp objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"ProfileImage"];

    if ([imageUrl isEqualToString:@"No Image"]) {
        pinImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-icon-1.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        //   pinImage=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[temp objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"ProfileImage"]]]];
        pinImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-icon-1.png"];

    }

    [listOfImagesArray addObject:pinImage];

    CLLocation* currentLocation = (CLLocation*)customAnnotation ;
    if(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude > maxLat)
        maxLat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    if(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude < minLat)
        minLat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    if(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude > maxLon)
        maxLon = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    if(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude < minLon)
        minLon = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;

    region.center.latitude     = (maxLat + minLat) / 2;
    region.center.longitude    = (maxLon + minLon) / 2;
    region.span.latitudeDelta  =  maxLat - minLat;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = maxLon - minLon;
}

[myMapview setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

}